# Can I receive data from a port on my website

Tags: java, php, vb.net, apache

My background is VB.net,

I have a device that sends data via a socket to my website www.3dweb2010.net on port 80 and I need to receive that data and save it in a database.  I do not have much knowledge of web design and am completely stuck as to where to look and what to look for.

As you can see the website currently has an index page and thats it!

The data is just a string being sent to the ipaddress/web site name using a socket on a specific port

Can anyone help?

Comment: Port 80 is designated to web page requests so this will cause problems. You might want to select a different port number then investigate SOAP.

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look, I have tried other ports - changing that isn't a problem

Comment: Not getting very far with SOAP! Help :-(